# JavaScript not compiling

Tags: javascript, algorithm, modulus

I've been trying to get the following algorithm to work for some time now, I believe that the problem is that x is too high a number. Is there a way around this that will allow the code to compile and won't cause the browser to crash?

```
var x=600851475143;
var prime=0;
for(var i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    if(x%i===0)
    {
          prime=i;  
    }
}
console.log(prime);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I'm pretty sure the code "compiles" fine (there are no syntax errors).

Comment: Javascript isn't compiled.  Your problem is that your code is too slow.

Comment: it finds the largest factor of that big number? And does 600 trillion divides in the process.

Comment: Why not let your loop run backwards and break? (which would make it about 1.4% faster…)

Comment: [The simple solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+600851475143)

Comment: And while you are running backwards, start from x/2.

Comment: Yeah it's an Euler puzzle, compiling it on the browser and keeps crashing. I guess going backwards would make much more sense... Cheers!

Comment: Im sure the browser is not actually crashing -- you probably getting an error message saying that the browser has become non-responsive -- which is caused by the very long run time of the loop and not from any actual crash.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, by starting with the smaller factor and stopping when it has found the first:

```
var x = 600851475143;
var prime=0;
for (var i=2, l=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(x)); i<l; i++) {
    if (x%i === 0) {
        prime=x/i;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(x, i, prime);
// Notice that `prime` is not (necessarily) a prime number, it's just
// the largest factor of x (below x itself).
// 600851475143 = 71 * 8462696833
```

Comment: As a potential cost-saving operation, i = 2 can be checked first, and then odd numbers from `for(var i = 3; ... ; i+=2) will decrease the number of for loop iterations by half`

Comment: @Compass: Of course, you could also [take all known primes](https://oeis.org/A000040) until `x` and test for each of them.

Comment: But then we're using up precious bytes! I'll never get that all to fit into a code golf! :P